# How to rotate one circle anti clockwise canvas android

Tags: java, android, rotation, geometry

I can't solve problem and I need help. I create planets around sun to rotate and I need one planet t rotate anti clockwise and my problem begins. I try everything I'm familiar. I'm beginner and this is simple code but I cant solve it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

I tried with getting anti clockwise just putting minus and this not work. I try with radius and angle and didn't work. I somewhere getting failed in code but I don't know where.

...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    screenDimensions = getDisplayDimensions();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1200, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.eraseColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint1 = new Paint();
    paint2 = new Paint();
    paint3 = new Paint();
    paint4 = new Paint();

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    paint1.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint4.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);


    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            animationFrame();

                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }, 2000, 80);


}

private int[] getDisplayDimensions() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    return new int[]{width, height};
}

private void animationFrame() {

    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#EBEBEB"));

    paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    canvas.drawCircle(500f, 750f, 130f, paint);


    if (paint1 != null | paint3 != null) {

        paint1.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(400f, 560f, 51f, paint1);
        canvas.rotate(10f, 500f, 750f);


        paint3.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.rotate(30f, 500f, 750f);
        canvas.drawCircle(350f, 1050f, 45, paint3);


    }
    if (paint2 != null | paint4 != null) {

        paint2.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        canvas.rotate(-10f, 500f, 750f);
        canvas.drawCircle(720f, 950f, 48, paint2);

        paint4.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.rotate(-25f, 500f, 750f);
        canvas.drawCircle(290f, 330f, 42, paint4);

    }

    imageView.invalidate();
}

}
```

...

I expected to one of planets get rotation anticlockwise.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

This code works perfectly for me:

In your case, the rotationPoint is the center point of sun and the bodyCenter is the center point of a planet.

Final points cx and cy are the center point of a planet after rotation around the sun.

```
    class Vector {
        float x;
        float y;

        Vector(float x, float y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
```

```
    public Vector getRotatedPoint(boolean isClockwise, float rotation, Vector bodyCenter, Vector rotationPoint){
        float sin = MathUtils.sin(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        float cos = MathUtils.cos(rotation * MathUtils.degreesToRadians);
        float xSin = (bodyCenter.x - rotationPoint.x) * sin;
        float xCos = (bodyCenter.x - rotationPoint.x) * cos;
        float ySin = (bodyCenter.y - rotationPoint.y) * sin;
        float yCos = (bodyCenter.y - rotationPoint.y) * cos;
        float cx, cy;
        if (isClockwise) {
            //For clockwise rotation
            cx = rotationPoint.x + xCos + ySin;
            cy = rotationPoint.y - xSin + yCos;
        } else {
            //For counter clockwise rotation
            cx = rotationPoint.x + xCos - ySin;
            cy = rotationPoint.y + xSin + yCos;
        }
        return new Vector(cx, cy);
    }
```

to use it you have to call first the method and then draw a circle

```
Vector newCenter = getRotatedPoint(true, 10f, planetCenter, sunCenter)
canvas.drawCircle(newCenter.x, newCenter.y, 48, paint2);
```

Comment: I just write that code and replace with numbers of planets and sun or just write it just as you show me? Sorry for aksing I'm beginner and is little hard to understand. Thank you a lot

Comment: You have to create a method from it. You will pass the following parameters center point of the sun (x, y), the center point of a planet (x, y) and rotation in degrees eg -30. this method will return a new center point of the planet (cx, cy).

Comment: can you edit my code because I dont know where to put and how.. if you want I'll be thankfull to the sky.